# Has somebody tried the new Licensing service already?

Tags: android, piracy-prevention

Yesterday google released a new service regarding the android market. A new way to check the licensing of your applications. See the [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/licensing-service-for-android.html) for more informations.

Has anybody updated her/his app already? How is it working for you? Are there any problems with it? Would you wait some days to see if there are severe bugs left that won't be found until the mass of apps hits the licensing server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Works great.  Caught my first pirate that was foolish enough to email me and wonder why the app doesn't work anymore.  I was part of their beta program, so it has been in use with a limited of folks for awhile now.  The library works very well and provides a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Tried it myself and works like a charm but we don't have much sales until now so that may change.